# How to cache web to read offline in webcontrol window phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, web-controls, offline-caching

I'm using  to load website follow code

```
webContent.Navigate(new Uri(linkURL));
```

I want to cache all content and html tag, style, js in web to read offline.

I tried download html source, file css and js using **Webclient** and **replace** these file to html resource then save to file "*index.htm*" but not good.

Can you find the way to resolve this issue? thank you.

Comment: Using your favorite browser navigate to your favorite web page. Do File - Save - Make sure you select the option that gives all the content in a folder (not a MHT file). See what the browser did, that's what you need to reproduce.

Comment: @CosminPrund IE on Windows Phone does not include a Save option. (Or a file menu for that matter). The question also asks about doing it in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is to download ALL the relevant files (including those referenced inside the HTML. eg. images, css, js, etc.) and save them ALL to Isolated Storage with appropriate similar file and folder structures.

The important point is that you also need to update all the paths within the content so that they point to relative paths that match where files have been saved.

You can then load the HTML from IsolatedStorage.

This is potentially a lot of work. I'd recommend exploring other options if possible first.  Also remember to manage the files stored in IsolatedStorage appropriately so you don't just keep adding files there indefinitely.